# Insert Column A from all sheets into column A of a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to stack all of the values from all sheets' column A into a new sheets' Column A. The columns are of different lengths depending on the sheet. I was successful with inserting the columns previously but it inserted the formulas not the values of the columns and it inserted them horizontally not vertically.

```
Sub Vlookpage()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

'add sheet and name it lookup
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Lookup"
'take all column "A"s and add them to "vlookup"
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count - 1
    Worksheets(i).Range("A:A").Copy
    Worksheets(i).Range("A:A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Worksheets(i).Range("A:A").Copy
    Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A:A").Insert (xlShiftDown)
        Next i
'purge duplicates
    Worksheets("Lookup").Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates
End Sub
```

The columns are still being inserted horizontally rather than stacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Vlookpage()
 Dim WS As Worksheet, shLkp As Worksheet, i As Integer
 Dim lastRowL As Long, lastRowWs As Long, arrAA

   'add sheet and name it lookup
    Set shLkp = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
    shLkp.Name = "lookup"

   'take all column "A"s and add them to "vlookup"
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> shLkp.Name Then
            lastRowWs = WS.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            lastRowL = shLkp.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlUp).row
            arrAA = WS.Range("A1:A" & lastRowWs).Value

            shLkp.Range("A" & lastRowL + 1).Resize(UBound(arrAA), 1).Value = arrAA
        End If
    Next WS
   'purge duplicates
    shLkp.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! I changed the remove duplicates a bit because there were spare blanks, but otherwise this is exactly the code I was looking for!

Comment: @Michael: I only followed your code (deduced) logic and make it work. So, should I understand that the above code did  not answer your question?

Comment: @Michael - as you commented this answer as "Perfect!" it would be good use to accept it by ticking the green checkmark, too.